# Screen started flickering after or while playing game, driver display encountered error

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, display, nvidia-graphics-card

Just as the title said, the screen started flickering. Some part of the pixel started breaking apart and the color turned weird. Then (in some cases) the whole screen will blacked out momentarily and restarted again without any problem. A notification of "Display driver stopped working and has recovered" will appear.
I've tried reinstalling it, increasing it's power setting to the max, and updating the driver to the current most version.
My graphic card is Nvidia GeForce GT630 4Gb. Any help is appreciated. Thank you~

Comment: Have you tried any hardware diagnostics?  This seems like it could be a flaky or overheating video card or even be a bad monitor.

Comment: Ah, maybe I'll try vacuuming the pc. Might be the dust too. Hardware diagnostic?

Comment: There are a variety of diagnostics that can test your hardware.  At this point, it's just to rule out the hardware side of things causing the issue.  I find it's usually a good thing to start with testing the hardware for faults first, then if that tests good, figure out the software issue.  I've seen people try un/installing software for days, only to find out that the hardware was bad.

Comment: Hiren's Boot CD and Ultimate Boot CD are what I generally used when I was a computer tech.  There's others out there that can be Googled.

Comment: HIren's Boot CD, eh? Got it, I'll try that. Let's hope it's not fauty hardware since if it is, I will need to save up to get something for that.